# Groovy: Iterate and multiply

Tags: list, groovy

I want to multiply every item in a list. But this example just returns every item:

```
list = 1..10
println list.each{it*2}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use collect().

i.e.

```
list = 1..10
println list.collect{it*2}
```

Gives

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Comment: My bad, try again. Haha, I should really read the question properly first.

Comment: No problem, approve in your own time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Only the syntax of Groovy is pegged to be standardized, not the default methods, so different implementations of Groovy have different names for the specific method to use.

In Codehaus Groovy (v 2.1.9 at groovy.codehaus.org) use `collect`...

```
list = 1..10
println list.collect{it*2}
```

In Real Groovy (v 0.10.0 at realgroovy.codeplex.com) use the more standardly named `map`...

```
test{
  is [1,2,3,].map{it*7} == [7,14,21]
}
```

I'm not sure how GrooScript (at www.grooscript.org) does it.